# Django 2 Template inexistente

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

No meu projeto tenho um projeto com 2 apps.
A primeira app é learning_logs que possui um template, base.html
A segunda app é users, estou tentando utilizar o template do learning_logs no users da seguinte forma:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}
```

Acontece que a app que está tentando usar o template, está procurando dentro da sua própria app, e como não encontra está aparecendo msg de template inexistente.

Answer (score 0):

Tirei o nome da app onde está o template e funcionou.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```